# How do I show one swal at the time in javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval, sweetalert

I created a swal for a notification. To show up in the screen the result of the ajax function has to be 0. But this ajax function run every 2 seconds. Sometimes the ajax function returns more than one result has 0, so the swal dont stop showing, just showing the other when the user click in the close button. I would like to show one swal at the time, but setInterval function isnt alowing me to do it.

This is the funtion with the swal:

```
 function montarModalLigacao(cdRamalLigacao = null)    
    {
      var dsHtml = buscaDadosAjax('Ramal', 'obtemHtmlLigacao', {cdLigacaoRamal: cdRamalLigacao});
      console.log(dsHtml);
      if (dsHtml)
      {
        swal({
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          allowEnterKey: false,
          showCloseButton: true,
          showCancelButton: true,
          title: 'Recebendo Chamada',
          html: dsHtml,
          cancelButtonText:'Fechar',
          confirmButtonText: 'Lançar Ticket',
          width: '80%'
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value)
            pop_open('man_atendimento_ticket.php?f_id_retorno=70&f_cd_ticket=');
        });
      }
    }
```

And here is where i call it, with the setInterval:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
          retorno = buscaDadosAjax('Ramal', 'verificarLigacao', {});
          if (parseInt(retorno.id_capturado) === 0)
            montarModalLigacao(retorno.cd_ramal_ligacao);
   }, 2000);  
}
```

Comment: So do not use an interval, trigger a function to set a timeout when the person answers the previous alert.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do it on an interval, call it when you are ready for the next one to happen.

```
function montarModalLigacao(cdRamalLigacao = null) {
  var dsHtml = buscaDadosAjax('Ramal', 'obtemHtmlLigacao', {
    cdLigacaoRamal: cdRamalLigacao
  });
  console.log(dsHtml);
  if (dsHtml) {
    swal({
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      allowEnterKey: false,
      showCloseButton: true,
      showCancelButton: true,
      title: 'Recebendo Chamada',
      html: dsHtml,
      cancelButtonText: 'Fechar',
      confirmButtonText: 'Lançar Ticket',
      width: '80%'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value)
        pop_open('man_atendimento_ticket.php?f_id_retorno=70&f_cd_ticket=');
      setUpCall();
    });
  } else {
    setUpCall();
  }
}

function setUpCall() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    retorno = buscaDadosAjax('Ramal', 'verificarLigacao', {});
    if (parseInt(retorno.id_capturado) === 0)
      montarModalLigacao(retorno.cd_ramal_ligacao);
  }, 2000);
}

$(document).ready(setUpCall);
```

Comment: But I have to check every 2 seconds if the ajax is returning value, thats why I have to use setInterval

Comment: Well it will check 2 seconds after they interact with the alert.